# How to get face points in 2D space from Kinect 2 SDK?

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to get 2D points of face from Kinect 2 SDK. This is easy to do from C++ using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.face.highdetailfacepoints.aspx but I am not able to find something similar in C#.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".